# Authorization grant flow failed when linking account with Google Home device

Tags: java, rest, actions-on-google, oltu

I'm able to redirect authorization code back to redirect url which can be seen in oauth2.0 playground tool.But i am getting null values in parameters like client_id,client_secret,grant_type and code when accessing token from authorization server.Here is the redirect url sending authorization code

> https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/skillid?state=xyz&code=aW1vbml
>
> Http/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   {
>     "error_description": "Bad Request", 
>     "error": "invalid_grant"}

`OAuthASResponse.OAuthAuthorizationResponseBuilder builder = OAuthASResponse .authorizationResponse(request,HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);' builder.setParam("code", token); 
builder.setParam("state", state); 
final OAuthResponse response = builder.location(redirectURI).buildQueryMessage();
URI url = new URI(response.getLocationUri()); return Response.status(response.getResponseStatus()).location(url).build();`

Comment: Can you provide additional details about which authorization flow you're using (Implicit or Authorization Code)?

Comment: I am using Authorization grant code method using apache oltu oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that i have to use @Formparameters to pick post request for authrization grant flow to exchange token with authorization code.